# Why does this SQL query give a syntax error?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT * 
FROM debates
WHERE assertion LIKE '%inspiration%' OR '%X%'
```

> PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type boolean: "%x%" LINE 1: ...FROM debates WHERE assertion LIKE '%inspiration%' OR '%x%' ^

It works with sqlite

Comment: Why? Because it's invalid SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it works on sqlite and I tried it out in sqlitespy by running the sql and it worked and it worked in my web browser too.

Comment: Well then SQLite supports non-standard SQL. It **is** invalid according to the SQL standard. I would think that essentially every other DBMS would also reject this (Oracle, DB2, Firebird, SQL Server will most definitely do)

Comment: I got it from w3schools.

Comment: w3schools is known to be full of errors. You should rather read the Postgres manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify column explicitly like:

```
SELECT *
FROM debates
WHERE assertion LIKE '%inspiration%' 
   OR assertion LIKE '%X%'
```

You can try also:

```
SELECT  * 
FROM debates t
JOIN
(
    SELECT '%inspiration%' Col
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT '%X%'
) List 
ON t.assertion LIKE List.Col
```

Answer (score 1):

`or` connects boolean expressions.  A string constant is not a boolean expression.

This is standard SQL (and common to most languages that use `or` in this fashion).  The answer is simple:

```
where assertion like '%inspiration%' or assertion like '%x%'
```

or use regular expressions:

```
where assertion ~ 'inspiration|x'
```